# Joomla issue with php

Tags: php, joomla

I'm getting this issue with my joomla site:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Browser' not found in /home/heidivision/pmbrandvold.com/templates/js_wright/wright/doctypes/default.php on line 66
```

I'm running the JS Wright template by Joomlashack on Joomla 2.5 - I did update a few extensions, but I honestly can't remember which ones...I didn't think the template was updated at all, but that's when it broke.

Comment: The error tells you the script, line number and class name that was not found. Have you tried debugging this yourself?

Comment: `Browser` is not a default Joomla class, however `JBrowser` is. Try changing it to this and see what the outcome is

Comment: @Lodder, that did the trick! Thank you so much.

Comment: @MasterModnar - I've written a proper answer as it solved the issue. please mark it as accepted so other know it has been solved. Would you also be able to contact the developer as recommended on the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write this as an answer so other can easily see it's the solutions.

`Browser` is not a default class that belongs to Joomla, but `JBrowser` is. So assuming that template developer was trying to utilize this, find the line where the error is coming from and replace `Browser` with `JBrowser`.

I'd also suggest telling the developer of the template so they can fix it in their next update.